# How to create passthrough effect in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can somebody tell me how I can achieve a passthrough effect in unity 2d? What I mean by this is that the player should be able to see their character before entering, but then have their character partially blocked when in between. Here is an example of what I am looking for: [Cuphead passing through tree entrance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQIIU.png)

Please help me out and thank you in advance!

Comment: Make blocking object separate from background and place closer.

Comment: Can you explain that in more detail? I am still a beginner.

Comment: That tree is actually composed of (at least) 2 objects: background image and blocking image. Background image is placed at back compared to the character so player can see the character. However blocking image is placed at front so when it overlaps with character, player isn't able to see the character. Those two images are drawn and placed seamlessly so that they look like a single image.

Comment: That's one possible example(I don't really know how developers implemented it) and there can be other ways to achieve it such as masking. But what I explained is probably the easiest and most straightforward way.